# How to format date in single quoted string "yyyy-mm-dd" in python?

Tags: python, pandas

How to format date in single quoted string "yyyy-mm-dd" in python that matches the following regex?

```
r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\''
```

The code:

```
pmax=df5.iloc[:,-5]  # maximum pressure
pmin=df5.iloc[:,-4]   # minimum pressure

df5['PressureDiff']=pmax-pmin
pm=df5["PressureDiff"].max()
df5=df5.loc[df5.PressureDiff==pm]
df5=pd.to_datetime(df5['Day']).dt.date   

from datetime import datetime
max_p_range_day = ## format as yyyy-mm-dd enclosed in single quotes
t=open("handson_date.txt",'w')
t.write("max_p_range_day = %s" % max_p_range_day)
```

For testing the file where I wrote my answer, code is as follows:

```
x=open("handson_date.txt",'r')
out=x.read()
res=re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

How to format the date to match the following regex?

Comment: Have you tried the `strftime()` function of `datetime`?

Comment: Look into [`strptime()`/`strftime()` behavior / format-codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: for today date `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'")` - `'2021-01-08'`

Comment: or even `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("max_p_range_day = '%Y-%m-%d'")` - `max_p_range_day = '2021-01-08'`

Answer (score 0):

To format `datetime` you have `strftime()`

For today date

```
 datetime.datetime.now().strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'")
```

Result (and `' '` is part of result)

```
'2021-01-08'
```

You can even use it with other text

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("max_p_range_day = '%Y-%m-%d'")
```

Result

```
max_p_range_day = '2021-01-08'
```

And the same you can do even in `DataFrame`

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
today = datetime.datetime.today()

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [today, today-one_day, today+one_day]})
print(df)


result = df['date'].dt.strftime("max_p_range_day = '%Y-%m-%d'")
print(result)
```

Result

```
                        date
0 2021-01-08 10:12:51.295168
1 2021-01-07 10:12:51.295168
2 2021-01-09 10:12:51.295168


0    max_p_range_day = '2021-01-08'
1    max_p_range_day = '2021-01-07'
2    max_p_range_day = '2021-01-09'
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

**EDIT:**
You have to add `' '` around `%s` in `"max_p_range_day = '%s'"`

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

max_p_range_day = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")   # <-- without `' '`
print('data:', max_p_range_day)

t = open('handson_date.txt', 'w')
t.write("max_p_range_day = '%s'" % max_p_range_day)  # <-- add `' '`
t.close()   # need it to correctly save all data

# ---------------------

x = open('handson_date.txt')
out = x.read()

print('out:', out)

res = re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)

if res:
    res = res[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
    print('found:', res)
else:
    print('?')
```

---

Or you have to use `' '` in `strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'")`

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

max_p_range_day = datetime.today().strftime("'%Y-%m-%d'")  # <-- add `' '`

print('data:', max_p_range_day)

t = open('handson_date.txt', 'w')
t.write("max_p_range_day = %s" % max_p_range_day)  # <-- without `' '`
t.close()   # need it to correctly save all data

# ---------------------

x = open('handson_date.txt')
out = x.read()

print('out:', out)

res = re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)

if res:
    res = res[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
    print('found:', res)
else:
    print('?')
```

Comment: I wrote max_p_range_day = datetime.strftime(df5.values[0],"max_p_range_day = '%Y-%m-%d'"). The error was as follows:   max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")

E   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: first check what you get for `findall` - error can means you get empty list and you can't get `[0]` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: you could also use `print()` and `print(type())` to check values in other variables. What do you have in `out`? I don't see how you create `out`. Maybe `out` has something different then you expect.

Comment: x=open("handson_date.txt",'r')
out=x.read()    On doing: re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0],         output is: "max_p_range_day = '2018-03-23'"

Comment: I don't know what exactly you have in file. As before: `findall()` may gives you empty list and then `[0]` doesn't exist - and you get error. You should first check what you get with `findall()` - ie. `data = findall(...)` and `if data: res = data[0]` . And you should first check `print( x )` because you may have different text then you expect.

Comment: now I see your problem - `write("max_p_range_day = %s" % max_p_range_day)`  - you forgot `' '` in `"max_p_range_day = '%s'" so you create file with `' '` and later `findall()` can't find expected string because data in file has no `' '`. You should see this if you would first check `print(out)`

Comment: I added two examples which shows where you can add `' '` to create correct file.

Comment: Thank you. After rectifying the issue strftime() worked.